# Is it possible to set the icon or launch screen in Xcode programmatically?

Tags: ios, xcode, icons

I have an app that would get used by different clients with slight tweaks for each client, including a different icon and launch screen. Is it possible to program the app to grab those images off of a server and use them, or would I need to manually put them into each iteration of the app the normal way?

Comment: I've seen apps that let you put a different background image on the launch screen so I know that is possible programmatically. I'd be surprised if Apple would make it easy to change the launch icon programmatically, but if there's no immediate way to do it, it is contained in the assets file so you'd probably have to read that file and replace the icon in all resolutions and it would probably show up at re-launch. Maybe someone else has a better answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is impossible to change the `App Icon` programmatically using only public `API` as well as change `launch screen` at runtime. You may create some kind of "fake"-`launch screen`, that will be the first `UIViewController` in your app and will dismiss automatically short after being presented.