# Is there any way that can edit the launch screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have followed the tutorial of the link at the below:

http://oleb.net/blog/2014/08/replacing-launch-images-with-storyboards/

However, it do not run any code in the viewDidLoad. Also, the launch screen turns black when i use the IBoutlet for the UILabel.

Is there any way the i can edit the UILabel in UIViewController?

Comment: No, the launch storyboard or nib is only loaded but never is there any code run.

Comment: Check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332176/is-it-possible-to-set-the-icon-or-launch-screen-in-xcode-programmatically/29332963#29332963)

Comment: You cannot use your class in LaunchScreen.xib so none of your code will be run in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you're testing in on a device with iOS 7 or less.

You can only specify a launch screen xib for iOS 8.

Earlier versions require launch image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other "solution" which make a fake launch screen (the first UIViewController in Main.Storyboard) and set the Main.Storyboard to be the launch screen. Then insert the code in viewDidLoad()

swift:

```
let delay = 3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourVCIdentifierInStoryboard", sender: self)
}
```